# Snowflake - referencing alias on SELECT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am searching for rationale behind following behaviour:

```
SELECT RANDOM() AS col, col + 1 AS col2
-- works
```

but

```
SELECT RANDOM() AS col, (SELECT col + 1) AS col2
-- error
```

while:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT RANDOM() AS col
)
SELECT col, (SELECT col + 1) AS col2
FROM cte;
-- works
```

Is this by design? Are columns evaluated in specific order(I guess left-to-right) which makes perfect sense, but what with nested `SELECT` as presented?

Comment: I think the last query should end with "FROM cte"

Answer (score 0):

In `SELECT RANDOM() AS col, (SELECT col + 1) AS col2` the clause `SELECT col + 1` is evaluated first which means that the value of col has not yet been assigned.

Comment: Any official reference to support that claim. In standard SQL the columns in the SELECT list are evaluated in any order([all-at-once operation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx)). I know that Snowflake handles it differently and I would like to know how it is performed.